# What is the best way to determine object pointer by pointer to one of it's members?

Tags: c++, pointers, structure, c++14

Like if I have:

```
struct S
{
    std::size_t szArray;
    int dArray[];
} ;

int main()
{
    extern int (*pArr)[]; //pointer to member 'dArray' of object with type 'S'

    S *pStruct = /*??????????*/; //pointer to the object
}
```

What is the best way to get this pointer?

Comment: You do know that arrays naturally decays to pointers to their first element? Also, standard C++ doesn't support flexible arrays in structures, if you have an array in a structure it must have a size at compile-time, otherwise use a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: I know that but I want to use pointer to arrays in order to preserve the information that they point to multiple objects instead of one. Anyway - I don't know why I left with the impression that flexible arrays are supported in C++ but in every case that doesn't change the situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no good way to do that.

The only supported way is

```
#include <cstddef> // for offsetof

S *pStruct = reinterpret_cast<S*>
    (reinterpret_cast<char*>(pArr) - offsetof(S, dArray));
```

Beware that `offsetof` is only well-defined for standard-layout types, and that standard C++ doesn't allow unsized arrays as class members. Unless you've got a good reason for using C idioms, I'd suggest that `std::vector<int>` would be safer and more convenient.

Comment: I would put `static_assert(std::is_standard_layout<S>(), "S must be standard layout for this to work.");` in there to (a) make it obvious what is going on, and (b) future-proof.

Comment: A size 1 array can be used to replace the empty array.  The technique of allocating "extra space" after the end of the array may be valid?  And "over-indexing" into it might be guaranteed to work?  But I am unsure.  If it isn't guaranteed, it should be, as it is a pretty typical C technique, and I cannot think of an implementation (with POD types) that wouldn't work with it.  Amusingly, you might want 2 structures -- one with just the size, and one with the size and a 1 element array -- to make the standard layout guarantees work for you.

Comment: @Yakk: Yes, the idiom can be made to work in C++, if you've got a good reason. But as I said, you'd need a good reason, since it's much less safe and convenient than the equivalent C++ idioms.

Comment: What bothers me here is if 'char' is guaranteed to be with the size of a single byte.

Comment: @FISOCPP: Yes, by definition.